# Why am I getting ZeroDivisionError when attempting to divide these results in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On the below pandas example, I get different results with CASE 1 returning a result while CASE 2 raises a ZeroDivisionError (float division by zero). Only difference is the numerator format which is forced to float for CASE 1.

Any background on this would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['apple',  True,  1.0],
                   ['apple',  False, 2.0],
                   ['banana', True,  3.0],
                   ['banana', False, 4.0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.loc[df['A'] == 'apple', ['B', 'C']] = np.nan
df
Out[2]: 
        A      B    C
0   apple    NaN  NaN
1   apple    NaN  NaN
2  banana   True  3.0
3  banana  False  4.0
# [CASE 1] : numerator dtype column is float -> division by zero is ok
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').astype(float) / df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
Out[3]: 
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.142857
3    0.142857
dtype: float64
# [CASE 2] : numerator dtype column is object -> division by zero raises an Error
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum') / df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
Traceback (most recent call last):
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum')
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
Name: B, dtype: object

df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').dtype
# dtype('O')
```

Notice the output of the transformation is of dtype('O') for object type. This is because column B is mixing bools and floats, resulting in the output dtype not being a native dtype that pandas/numpy supports.

Thus, calling division on this will fallback to pure iterative python division which always raises a `ZeroDivisionError`:

```
>>> 0 / 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-580a5669e7f6> in <module>
----> 1 0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Contrast this with the first approach that converts the result to a numpy native dtype such as float:

```
>>> np.float32(0) / 0
nan
```

Note this would also work if you converted the result to numpy int:

```
(df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').astype(int) 
   / df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum'))
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.142857
3    0.142857
dtype: float64
```

The key here is to avoid columns/results that have dtype = object, since pandas can't vectorize operations on those. You'll also see performance boosts if you fill NaNs before grouping:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(False)

df.dtypes
A     object
B       bool
C    float64
dtype: object
```

And thus no explicit cast is needed:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum') / df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.142857
3    0.142857
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Division by zero with two non-zero numbers of the same type returns `inf` or `-inf`But division by zero with a float and a non-float raises a `ZeroDivisionError` because the division operator / in Python 3.x performs true division by default, which always returns a float, even if both operands are integers.

In the case of the provided example, the difference between CASE 1 and CASE 2 is the data type of the numerator column. In CASE 1, the numerator column is cast to a float using the astype(float) method, so it is safe to perform the division even if the denominator contains a zero value. In CASE 2, the numerator column is not cast, so it retains its original data type, which is an object.

You should use your first approach

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').astype(float) / df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum').astype(float)
```

which gives

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.142857
3    0.142857
dtype: float64
```